# Parsing list of desired files python

Tags: python, parsing, python-xarray

I have folders that contain netCDF files, which are named according to the hour of data they contain (i.e. S20160307T000000.nc through S20160308T000000.nc in one folder). I am combining multiple netCDF files into one, which I have done with:

```
import netCDF4
import numpy
import xarray
import glob
import os

files = sorted(glob.glob('/path/to/date/file/0307', recursive = True))

ds = xarray.open_mfdataset(files,concat_dim=['time'],
                       combine='nested',parallel=True)

varss = ['vbins', 'height', 'secs', 'snr', 'snc', 'Ze', 'vel', 'Zec']

ds[varss]

ds[varss].to_netcdf('/save/to/same/path/S20160307T120004_combined.nc')
```

However, I would like to combine files from 1200 UTC one day to 1200 UTC to next day. These data are located in 2 separate folders. How can I  parse the list of desired files out from the total files and then feed it to the xarray function?

Thank you!

Comment: You can do this with list comprehensions, but without knowing the structure of the file name it is hard to give any specific answer. You will need to say what a typical file name looks like.

Comment: File names follow the structure of S20160307T000000.nc,  S20160307T010000.nc,  S20160307T020000.nc,  S20160307T030000.nc,  S20160307T040000.nc, etc